# Why doesn't accessing self's property raise compiler warning in block owned by self

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am a little confused about memory management/retain cycles. Here's a simple class:

```
@interface Test : NSObject {
    NSObject *objectA;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject *objectB;

- (void)methodA;
@end
```

Let's say I have a block owned by an instance of Test. In this block I do:

```
    objectA = nil;
```

I get a compiler waning saying that it's capturing self in this block and it's going to lead to retain cycles. Why? I don't see self here.

Then if I do:

```
self.objectB = nil;
```

No warning! If anything, I should expect a warning here.

Also if I do:

```
[self methodA];
```

I get a waring here. So I am not sure exactly what's happening behind the scenes. I would expect the first one to no give me a warnings, and the last 2 to give me a warning (since I am keep a strong pointer to self), but it's actually the opposite.

Here's an example:

```
@interface ListVC () {
    NSObject *objectA;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject *objectB;
- (void)methodA;
@end
```

and in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView addPullToRefreshWithActionHandler:^{
        self.objectB = nil; //no warning here
        objectA = nil; //warning here
        [self methodA]; //warning here (if i place this above previous warning
    }];
}
```

Comment: Is that how your .h is? `@interface Test ()` Because it looks like a category.

Comment: @JackyBoy it's just an example I quickly wrote. I don't have a .h or .m, I wrote on SO editor.

Comment: Well, we need to check everything in order to see what's wrong. I just tried on my code, setting an ivar to nil inside a block and everything went as expected. No warning. Do you have a code sample?

Comment: The first one (like any ivar access) is implicitly `self->objectB;` The Block retains `self` in that case, not the object in the ivar. Why the second one isn't warning I don't know; it should, because it's equivalent to the third.

Comment: @JackyBoy check update with example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like the compiler just isn't bothering to warn you multiple times for the same Block. I'm not sure that counts as a feature, but I can't see what else could be going on.

Assuming we're using the same compiler version (mine is Apple LLVM 4.2), try this:

```
@interface Jubilee : NSObject

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSData * d;

@end

@implementation Jubilee
{
    NSString * s;
    dispatch_block_t block;
}

@synthesize d;

- (void)erase
{
    block = ^{
        s = @"Agamemnon";
    };

    block = ^{
        self.d = [NSData data];
    };

    block = ^{
        [self prevaricate];
    };

}

- (void)assemble
{
    block = ^{
        s = @"Agamemnon";
        self.d = [NSData data];
        [self prevaricate];
    };
}

- (void)prevaricate
{
}

@end
```

I'm getting a warning at each Block inside `erase`, but only for the first line of the Block in `assemble`. The warning would be correct on any of these lines. When you make a bare reference to an ivar, it is implicitly `self->ivar;`, and the Block will retain `self` rather than the object in the ivar.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the detailed response. Also, I found that's sometimes, even for first line of the block it won't trigger a warning. For example if you do my_dictionary[@"hello"] = @"hi", even if it's first line...no warning generated. :( - I am guessing it has something to do using [] accessor on dictionary

Answer (score 3):

The first warning is correct. Accessing an instance variable within a block will implicitly retain self.
The fact that you don't get a warning for the second statement almost seems like a compiler bug.